# is the Jet Robot kit from Servocity discontinued?

Tags: ros, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It shows as out of stock and they can't give me a date when it will be in stock

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278425/is-the-jet-robot-kit-from-servocity-discontinued?/) by [Maghrebcity](https://answers.ros.org/users/33081/maghrebcity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:
Wouldn't asking Servocity directly be a more efficient way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may get all the parts yourself, as they are all available. Also the Excel spreadsheet parts list is available. (It's in the software package from Nvidia.) Perhaps Nvidia has their $199 special on the TX1 still going, I'm not sure. (Look on the developer's forum, page 1 for Jetson TX1.) For added vision capability, try the Intel Real sense D435 depth camera. JetsonHacks is just now posting scripts in Github to install the drivers on the TX1. This camera may be as capable as the Stereolabs Zed camera, at less than half the price.

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-04-11**:
This complete unit is now in stock, I see!